# Azure Autoscaling block cannot find certificate

Tags: azure, enterprise-library, autoscaling

I have the following situation: My azure application consists of 5 roles. One of those roles hosts the Autoscale block from Enterprise Library. This role is responsible for scaling the others up and down.

Now I followed the tutorial and added the Autoscale settings to the app.config and also added the services.xml and rules.xml.

The problem is that the autoscale logger (which works!) outputs this error over and over again:

> Could not retrieve the instance count for hosted service with DNS
>   prefix 'myCloudApp'.
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.Autoscaling.ServiceManagement.ServiceManagementClientException:
>   The service configuration could not be retrieved from Windows Azure
>   for hosted service with DNS prefix 'myCloudApp' in subscription id
>   'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' and deployment slot
>   'Production'. --->
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.Autoscaling.Security.CertificateException:
>   The certificate with thumbprint
>   'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' in store name 'My' and
>   store location 'LocalMachine' could not be found. at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.Autoscaling.Security.CertificateHelper.FindCertificate(StoreName
>   certificateStoreName, StoreLocation certificateStoreLocation, String
>   certificateThumbprint, Boolean withPrivateKey, Boolean validOnly) at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.Autoscaling.ServiceManagement.ServiceManagementClient.CreateFactory(StoreName
>   certificateStoreName, StoreLocation certificateStoreLocation, String
>   certificateThumbprint, Inspector inspector) at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.Autoscaling.ServiceManagement.ServiceManagementClient.CallOperation[TResult](Func`2
>   call, StoreName certificateStoreName, StoreLocation
>   certificateStoreLocation, String certificateThumbprint, String
>   exceptionMessage, String& requestId) --- End of inner exception stack
>   trace --- at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.Autoscaling.ServiceManagement.ServiceManagementClient.CallOperation[TResult](Func`2
>   call, StoreName certificateStoreName, StoreLocation
>   certificateStoreLocation, String certificateThumbprint, String
>   exceptionMessage, String& requestId) at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.Autoscaling.ServiceManagement.ServiceManagementClient.GetDeployment(String
>   hostedServiceDnsPrefix, String subscriptionId, DeploymentSlot
>   deploymentSlot, StoreName certificateStoreName, StoreLocation
>   certificateStoreLocation, String certificateThumbprint) at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.Autoscaling.ServiceManagement.ServiceManagementClientExtensions.GetDeployment(IServiceManagementClient
>   client, HostedService hostedService) at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.Autoscaling.DataPointsCollection.RoleInstanceCountDataPointsCollector.Collect(DateTimeOffset
>   collectionTime)

I replaced the actual thumbprint and subscription id with xxxxx.

I dont understand why it cannot access my cloud services. Do I need to do anything to this certificate?

Help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you actually upload the pfx (private key side) of the management certificate?  This error indicates it cannot find the cert installed on the machine.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg465712.aspx

Comment: The certificate is displayed in the azure management portal. Actually I have 5 certificates added there (don't know where they all come from though). I tried each one of them and always get the same error

Comment: Just to be clear - there is a difference between the management certificate uploads (pub key only) and the certificates you upload to the VM.  Do you have 5 management certs listed in portal, or have you uploaded 5 certs into the VM (totally different things)?

Comment: okay that was the problem. I was always using the management certificates... now at least this problem is solved. However, the next problem occurrs. New Error: Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'management.core.windows.net'. Do you know how to enable SSL?